# get code to reproduce plot of R object

Tags: r, object, plot

some packages have special plot objects, so when you do `plot(object)`
it produces one or several plots for this object.

An example is

```
data("cars")
m <- lm(dist~speed, data=cars)
plot(m)
```

which produces several plots to this linear model.

How can I get the code to these plots so I can manually reproduce them?
In this case `?plot.lm` has some more information, but that is not always the case.

To make it more clear, in this example the first plot is a residuals vs. fitted values plot, which I could get by `plot(m$fitted.values, m$residuals)`. I found this by analysing `str(m)`. In most cases this is not that obvious what the plot of an object does.

Comment: @jogo does not work. Also, there are package where `plot(object)` works but they have no `?plot.objecttype` help

Comment: `plot.lm` is a internal function, i.e. the R-code is not available. So one have to go to the source code of R. (For other functions R-code is available, example `plot.ts`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `getAnywhere` to see the codes inside a S3 function e.g. `plot.lm`.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

Use `edit(plot)` to know the structure of base-R function `plot`. To know the structure of your object use `edit(objName)`.